# PS: Why not solid color in my new layer

Tags: photoshop

I have approx 20 layers in a .psd file. Suddenly when I create a new layer I am not able to get a solid color, meaning I use 100% opacity but still get very light color?

The red color in picture is what I get when creating a new layer and add a color, the only thing I do. I have tried all kinds of things but not been successful.

**After tests I get the correct color when I create a rectangle but still what is on the picture when using the brush!**

[image: The result.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of tests and search I found a solution: Reset the Brush tool!

Comment: probably had a blend mode set on the brush

Comment: tx for comment, dunno that but will check next time it happens.